# How to handle multiple search condition of xpath in python Element Tree

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I want to extract some elements from a xml file by multiple search condition using Python(2.7.5) ElementTree.
the xml looks like:

```
   <src name="BdsBoot.c">
        <fn name="XXXXX" fn_cov="0" fn_total="1" cd_cov="0" cd_total="4">
           <probe line="113" kind="condition" event="full"/>
           <probe line="122" column="10" kind="condition" event="none" />
           <probe line="124" column="9" kind="condition" event="full" />
        </fn>
   </src>
```

I want the probe elements which kind="condition" and event="full"

I have tried

```
root.findall(".//probe[@kind='condition' and @event='full']") —— error
root.findall(".//probe[@kind='condition'] and .//probe[@event='full']") —— nothing
```

I read the simple introduction [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html),it seems that elementtree does not support and operator now?

is there any way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one:

```
root.findall('.//probe[@kind="condition"][@event="full"]')
```

Demo:

```
>>> s
'<src name="BdsBoot.c">\n        <fn name="XXXXX" fn_cov="0" fn_total="1" cd_cov="0" cd_total="4">\n           <probe line="113" kind="condition" event="full"/>\n           <probe line="122" column="10" kind="condition" event="none" />\n           <probe line="124" column="9" kind="condition" event="full" />\n        </fn>\n   </src>'
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> root.findall('.//probe[@kind="condition"]')
[<Element 'probe' at 0x7f8a5146ce10>, <Element 'probe' at 0x7f8a5146ce50>, <Element 'probe' at 0x7f8a5146ce90>]
>>> root.findall('.//probe[@kind="condition"][@event="full"]')
[<Element 'probe' at 0x7f8a5146ce10>, <Element 'probe' at 0x7f8a5146ce90>]
```

Comment: I have a new problem,how to use '..' to access the parent node?

Comment: You'd better post a new question. :( Because there is little info from your one sentence comment. I don't know how to answer.

Comment: just same as above,if i get a 'probe' node,how do i access its parent node('fn')?

Comment: `".//probe[@kind='condition' and @event='full']/.."`? I am not sure. Or there will `find_parent`?

Comment: you are right!there is no reference from child to parent,I have to find the parent starting with the root.